# How do I check if a string is convertable to a number

Tags: java, freemarker

In freemarker, I have a macro `myfunc` that does the following:

```
<#macro myfunc x>
  <#attempt>
    <#assign x=(x?number)>
  <#recover>
  </#attempt>
  ${x!''}
</#macro>
```

So, essentially, if `x` (which starts off as a string) and is convertible to a number, then I want to wrap it in `(${x})` otherwise just display the value.

I am fine with this solution except for the ugly `<#attempt>` error logging which comes with it.

There does not seem to be a simple way to check if a string is convertible to a number without using `<#attempt>` or my research is faltering -- I would also rather not do this on the Java side because I see this as view code and doesn't belong with my model code. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
<#if x?matches("\\d+")>
    // do something with x?number
<#else>
    // do something with x
</#if>
```